# Get cropped image via react-image-crop module

Tags: reactjs, react-image-crop

could you help me how can I get output (source of cropped image) via react-image-crop module?
Upload component looks like this:

```
class MyUpload extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        src: 'source-to-image',
        crop: {
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            aspect: 9 / 16,
            width: 100
        }
    }
}

onCropComplete = (crop, pixelCrop) => {
    this.setState({
        crop
    })
};

render() {
    return (
           <ReactCrop
                    src={this.state.src}
                    onComplete={this.onCropComplete}
                />
    );
} }
```

Method onCropComplete returns only coordinates, width and height of cropped image, not source. I would like to get blob file.

---

**EDIT (working solution -- thanks for Mosè Raguzzini reply):**

If someone has similiar problem, call *getCropptedImg* function from tutorial in your component and create url from returned Blob object, like this:

```
getCroppedImg(this.state.image, pixelCrop, 'preview.jpg')
            .then((res) => {
                const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(res);
                console.log(blobUrl); // it returns cropped image in this shape of url: "blob:http://something..."
            })
```

Comment: Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/72py4jlll6?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

react-image-crop is not meant to be used to produce blobs, is only meant to crop images inline. Probably you need something like https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

**UPDATE:**
Check the section "What about showing the crop on the client?" at bottom of
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop, the blob is available as hidden feature

```js
/**
 * @param {File} image - Image File Object
 * @param {Object} pixelCrop - pixelCrop Object provided by react-image-crop
 * @param {String} fileName - Name of the returned file in Promise
 */
function getCroppedImg(image, pixelCrop, fileName) {
 
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = pixelCrop.width;
  canvas.height = pixelCrop.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    pixelCrop.x,
    pixelCrop.y,
    pixelCrop.width,
    pixelCrop.height,
    0,
    0,
    pixelCrop.width,
    pixelCrop.height
  );
 
  // As Base64 string
  // const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
 
  // As a blob
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.toBlob(file => {
      file.name = fileName;
      resolve(file);
    }, 'image/jpeg');
  });
}
 
async test() {
  const croppedImg = await getCroppedImg(image, pixelCrop, returnedFileName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to overlook it.